# Reading a file into a vector all at once

Tags: c++, c++11, file-io

Is this a good idea for reading into a `std::vector`, or is there some gotcha here:

```
using namespace std;
ifstream file("blah.dat", ios::binary);

vector<T> v(N);

file.read(static_cast<char*>(v.data()), N * sizeof(T));
```

Does the `vector` standard allow me to do this to populate a vector?  For simplicities sake, let us assume that T is a Plain Old Data Type.

Comment: `size_of` == `sizeof`? Either way, be aware that the size of an object in memory does not necessarily correspond to the size of the object when written to a file (padding etc.) – it really depends on how the object was written to begin with.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks, fixed.  If written in this way (bad for portability, fine for my use case) by writing the memory explicitly, it should read back in this way.  I'm more curious about the `v.data` part.

Comment: You should specify what `T` is in order to get correct answers.  Is it a POD type?

Comment: Yes, it is a POD type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no undefined behavior here if `T` is trivially copyable, which PODs certainly are. `vector<T>::data` is guaranteed to return a pointer to a contiguous array of `vector<T>::size` `T`s, and the object representation of a trivially copyable type `T` is guaranteed to be a contiguous sequence of `sizeof(T)` bytes (possibly including internal padding).

If the bytes you store into that space aren't valid `T` object representations, you could get undefined behavior when you access them. Exactly which byte sequences constitute a valid `T` object representation is a bit of a grey area; at the very least you should be able to portably write the underlying bytes of an object of a trivially copyable type to file and successfully read them back into the underlying bytes of an object of the same type.

For paranoia's sake, I'd probably put:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>(),
              "NO NO NO - T MUST BE TRIVIALLY COPYABLE!");
```

before the `file.read` for future-proofing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would benefit from a memory mapped file. Boost provides two implementations, so you don't have to mess with `mmap()` directly.

Using [boost.iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html#mapped_file_source):

```
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>

boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source file("blah.dat");
std::size_t size = file.size() / sizeof(T);
const T * ptr = reinterpret_cast<const T*>(file.data());
for (std::size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
    std::cout << ptr[i] << std::endl;
```

You can also use [boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.html), but it requires more code for essentially the same functionality.

The main advantage is that you don't allocate any memory to access the file, it will be loaded on demand as the data is accessed. The data itself will live in cached/buffered pages, so it doesn't take any memory away (they are discarded if the system needs the memory for something else.)

Comment: Any way of controlling the cache size?

Comment: No, this is all handled by the OS; typically it will use all free pages as cache/buffers, since there's not much to gain by leaving RAM unused. That is, if your system has 8 GB, and only 1.5 GB is being used, then 6.5 GB will be available to the OS for caching.

Comment: Oh: one more question:  if two processes attempt to do a read only mmap on the same file,  will the file be loaded twice? or is the OS smart enough to only map it once?

Comment: I don't know of a single OS that would load mapped pages more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to do this, in fact what you're supposed to do (since the original C++) is this

```
std::ifstream file("foo.txt");
file >> std::noskipws;            // use this line so that whitespace won't be skipped
std::vector<char> buffer(std::istream_iterator<char>(file),
                         std::istream_iterator<char>());
```

The reason that you're not supposed to do it your way is because it makes no sense for an object to be living in a file (at least in C++).  Files only contain characters, that are then formatted by `operator>>` to create objects.  The standard allows the compiler to do some really weird things to an object (especially when RTTI is enabled) that make it useless to "save" an object to a file.  You are much better off just creating your own serialization format for it.

Comment: `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`. Your example will skip whitespace.

Comment: What if it isn't a vector of `char`?  Also, the file is in binary.  Can you give me some reason why I'm not supposed to do this?

Comment: So, the concept of "whitespace" is pretty pointless in a binary format.  And Plain Old Data Types (which is mostly what this would be for) map pretty well from memory to disk, which means, for my purposes "my own serialization format" is just mapping the memory directly to disk.  However, you haven't answered the other two questions I had.  Does this work for binary formats? and how do I generalize this for other kinds of `vector`s (not `char`  vectors).

Comment: @AndrewSpott The standard says that it is ***undefined behavior*** to "just [map] the memory to disk".  You can generalize this to ``vector<T>`` by defining the function ``std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, T&)`` (and doing that *is* defined by the standard).

Comment: Awesome.  Can you point out where in the standard it says that?

Comment: The file may want to be opened in *binary* mode so nothing gets *lost in translation*.

Comment: I don't get it. Your way, while better code, is functionally equivalent to the OP's way. So what do you mean when you say it's the way it's "supposed" to be done? Your argumentation is irrelevant because it doesn't hold for _either_ example.

Comment: @randomusername I still don't get why you don't just use `std::istreambuf_iterator`.